# Not able to call R code inside PHP script

Tags: php, r

I am trying to execute a small R code inside php program. Actually, the R code generates heatmap and save the figure in localfile. When I run the R code from command line, it works and save image file as follows,

```
Rscript /var/www/html/ani/Rcode/anat.R
```

But I am not able to perform this task when the code is called from php. I tried to use some methods to call the codes as something like this based on other posts,

```
exec("/usr/bin/Rscript /var/www/html/ani/Rcode/anat.R");
```

and

```
system("Rscript /var/www/html/ani/Rcode/anat.R");
```

It didnot work. So can anyone help me for solving the issue...Thanks.

R code,

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
dat <- read.csv("/var/www/html/ani/file.csv")
dat_matrix <- data.matrix(dat)
colors = c(seq(-2,-1,length=100),seq(-1,1,length=100),seq(1,2,length=100))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(n = 299)
png("/var/www/html/ani/Rcode/map.png")
heatmap.2(dat_matrix, dendrogram="none", Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, col = my_palette,     breaks=colors, scale="none", key=TRUE, density.info="none", trace="none", labRow=FALSE, symm=F,symkey=T,symbreaks=T)
dev.off()
```

PHP,

```
<?php
  .
  .
for ($i=0;$i<=$len;$i++)
{
$id=$locus[$i];
$id=trim($id);

$dbo = new PDO($dbc, $user, $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id='$id'";
$qry = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$qry->execute();

while ($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
      fputcsv($data, $row);
      chmod("file.csv",0777);
     }
}
exec("/usr/bin/Rscript /var/www/html/ani/Rcode/anat.R");

?>
```

Comment: It did not work means it printed out some error messages? Whatever? Please share.

Comment: Sorry..No it doesn’t display any error message in the browser..Also please note that nature of the work flow is 'when clicking the button, it calls the php program'

Comment: Argh. `var_dump(system(...))`?

Comment: have you seen this link? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/how-can-i-integrate-r-with-php

Comment: string(0) ""  is displayed in browser when I use `var_dump(system("Rscript /var/www/html/ani/Rcode/anat.R"));`. Sorry, I am new to php world..

Comment: It did not work when I used the exec() command as mentioned in the post. @Ehsan .

Comment: can you share your R script and the PHP code?

Comment: Yes I can..But how to dsiplay the two codes? I don have public ip...so is there any way? or should i paste here?@Ehsan

Comment: I added the R and PHP codes in main question @Ehsan

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? Are you expecting PHP to automatically display the image file? The code above will not do that, but perhaps it will nevertheless create the heatmap file. If you are certain it is not creating the heatmap file, then maybe it is a permissions issue with your web server. Can you run your PHP script from the command line? Try it and see what happens.

Comment: It is not working when run through browser (heatmap not saved). But when i run the php file from terminal, heatmap is generated as expected. Command used was `php /var/www/html/ani/alignment.php`@dash2